# strange behaviour with componentscan in spring boot

Tags: spring, components

I have 3 packages:

- mainpackage
- repositories
- controller

in my SpringBootApplication I have annotated:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"mainpackage","repositories","controller"})
```

In my repositories Package I have a component:

```
@Component
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

In my controller package I have a controller which autowires a component of 'repositories' :

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
```

which leads into :

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
```

What am I doing wrong ?

keeping all classes in one package works, but I like to have it a bit structured.

Comment: change UserRepository to `@Repository`

Comment: same issue. The spring container doesn't find the bean (either component or repository). I don't know why? When moving the userRepository to the mainpackage it works.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864261/how-to-inject-crudrepository-in-spring-jpa

Answer (score 0):

You're using `spring-data-jpa` repository, but it seems that you don't have any `@EnableJpaRepositories` in your SpringBootApplication class.

Please add it, e.g:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"mainpackage","repositories","controller"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("repositories")
```

and you might also need to add an `@EntityScan` with package where your entities resides:

```
@EntityScan("entities")
```